# laravel failing when url has /min

Tags: php, laravel, apache, url, google-cloud-platform

very strange error, when the url has /min it fails with error not found. it is very strange

for example xxx.com/mindfulness

it only fails when first part is /min

nothing related to routes because I tried removing alk of them

even maybe not related to laravel because if I add print_r on server.php I don't see any result.

something strange with the apache server?

the strange part is that with other subdomains it doesn't fail. only with the 2 projects with laravel

Comment: Don't get your question. Please rewrite it the way one can understand it. Do you have any code sample? do you have any error log? Please check [ask]

Comment: This could be secure mod or some sort of security plugin on your server.  if Route::get('mindfulness')  exists in laravel , then its server level ..  do php artisan route:list

Comment: nothing related to routes. as explained, I tried removing all the info from routes and same error. for the other guy, the explanation is perfect. if the path is xxxx.com/min you get not found. only happens when first slash is /minXXX. so with xxx.com/mind for example same not found. idem with xxx.com/mindfulness etc

Comment: i think it's nothing related to laravel because i added on the server.php file, the first one always executed , print_r with exit i you don't see any output. there must be something on apache server but trying with another project with code igniter on the same server you don't get the error